# Conditionally format a cell, or populate a cell based on the contents of another cell, if the 2nd if greater than 3.

Tags: excel, format, conditional-statements, lookup

I have a six digit reference in one cell.

On the same worksheet I would like to format a cell if the 2nd digit of the number is greater than 3.

I don't mind using a lookup rather than a conditional format. Because, I ideally I would like to put a cross "x" in the box, or at the very least grey out the box with formatting, if the 2nd digit in the referenced cell is greater than 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with that Formula:

```
=0+Left(Right(A1;2);1) >3
```

[image]

Her You can see it gets True (Wahr) or False(Falsch) when the 2nd digit is greater then 3.

And you can Put that in the Conditionally formating Like this:

[image]

[image]

I Hope that can Help you

Answer (score 0):

Let the reference be in cell A1. Put the following formula in B1 and apply conditional formating checking for >0:

=if(right(left(A1;2);1)*1;1;0)